# dup2 and pipe shenanigans with Python and Windows

Tags: python, windows

Say hello to `bug.py`:

```py
import os, sys

stdout2 = os.dup(sys.stdout.fileno())
(r,w) = os.pipe()
os.dup2(w,sys.stdout.fileno())
print("Hail Stan")
z = os.read(r,1000)
os.write(stdout2,z)
```

If you run this on OSX (and I imagine, on Linux), this works great. However, in Windows, we get this:

```
PS Z:\...> python --version
Python 3.9.2
PS Z:\...> python bug.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Z:\...\bug.py", line 6, in <module>
    print("Hail Stan")
OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect function
Exception ignored in: <_io.TextIOWrapper name='<stdout>' mode='w' encoding='utf-8'>
OSError: [WinError 1] Incorrect function
```

I don't know much about anything but this smells of some deep Python+Windows mysticism and PDB isn't cutting cheese so I can't debug my way out of this. Anyone knows how to make this work?

The slightly bigger context is that I'm trying to build some `tee`-like functionality into my application, but all other methods I've found of capturing stdout are incomplete. You can use popen and subprocess for various things, but if you truly want to grab your whole process's stdout and stderr, at least on Unix, the only way I found is to dup2 the filedescriptors through pipes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I've truly got to the bottomest bottom but I've mostly figured this one out.

`sys.stdout` is an object of type `TextIOWrapper`, whose `sys.stdout.write()` method eventually calls either `os.write()` or the C equivalent, on the filedescriptor `sys.stdout.fileno()`, which is 1. There are several types of filedescriptors: files, sockets, serial ports, terminals, pipes, etc... The C library functions `write()`, `close()`, etc... work on mostly any type of filedescriptor, but some features only work when the filedescriptor is of a suitable type. At creation time, the `TextIOWrapper` that is `sys.stdout` examines its filedescriptor (1) and determines that it's a terminal. On Windows only, `sys.stdout.write()` ends up doing some operations that are only valid if the filedescriptor 1 is truly a terminal. Once you `os.dup2()` so that 1 becomes an `os.pipe()`, and not a terminal, the Windows Python implementation crashes when it attempts to do terminal-specific operations on a pipe.

It's not clear to me that there's a way of causing `sys.stdout` to re-examine its filedescriptor so that it notices that it's not a terminal anymore, and avoid crashing the Python interpreter.

As a workaround, on Windows only, I'm doing `stdout.write = lambda z: os.write(stdout.fileno(),z.encode() if hasattr(z,'encode') else z)`

I haven't done a deep dive through the Python code base to see whether this is sufficient, but it does appear to allow my programs to run correctly, and `print()` no longer causes the Python interpreter to crash.

Many other people instead do `sys.stdout = ...`, but I did not want to do this for many reasons. For one, I was worried that some script or module might store a local cached copy of `sys.stdout`. Although it is possible to cache `sys.stdout.write` directly, I thought that this was less likely. Furthermore, it allows me to monkeypatch in my constructor, e.g. `StreamCapture(sys.stdout)`, without having to refer to the global variable `sys.stdout` directly in my constructor (a "side-effect"). If you believe that a function is allowed to mutate its inputs, then this is side-effect-free.